# wcf rest byte array gives bad request 400

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

Could someone clarify a piece of information I cannot put my finger on it...

According to tens of question on SO the only way to send `byte[]` is using 
`OperationContract` with a `Stream` parameter.

**Why is that** a wcf rest service cannot serialize a `byte[]` property, but if I use a string one instead and `Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)` everything goes well?

**EDIT 1**

```
[OperationContract] [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "Save/")]
Response Save(Document doc);
```

Now for the sake of the length I won't post the whole model.
There is a property in `Document` named `File` which has property of type `byte[]`.

Now in my client I have the following:

```
using (FileStream file = System.IO.File.Open(@"C:\D\pic.png", FileMode.Open))
                {
model.File = new File
                        {
                            FileName = "pic.png",
                            Description = "some description",
                            FileType = new Nomenclature { Id = 6 },
                            Content = file.ToByteArray(); // this is a function copied from SO and it works..
                        }


      ...some more property are being initialized here

                    var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
                    var content = new StringContent("{ \"doc\" : " + data + " }", Encoding.Unicode, "application/json");
                    var result =
                        client.PostAsync(new Uri("http://localhost/MyTestWCF/Save"), content)
                            .Result;
                    var tmp = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        });
                }
```

This results in 400 bad request

**However** if I use `Content` of type `string` and `Convert.ToBase64String(file.ToByteArray())` - it works perfectly

Comment: I've sent `byte[]` without using streams just fine.   Showing your code and the error you get would help us help you.

Comment: I am also having same issue.. how did you solve this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60714522/c-sharp-send-byte-as-json-to-wcf-rest-endpoint-400-bad-request